# Inserting chart images from Spreadsheet into Document using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

My script which is contained in a Spreadsheet creates a new Document and inserts tables and paragraphs based on the Spreadsheet data.  I also would like to insert charts (or jpg images of those charts) into the Document from the script. It seems to be possible, but does not work.  This is my code:

```
function insertChartImage(){
  var charts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Score Card').getCharts();
  var chart = charts[0].getAs('image/png');  // similar result with 'gif'
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);
  doc.getBody().appendImage(chart);          // similar result with insertImage()
}
```

The result is a [blank container](http://goo.gl/l35c3g)  result (and OF COURSE I'm signed in) saying "User not signed in".

I have sought far and wide for documentation, examples or tutorials but without any luck. Is this at all possible .... it seems like such a basic requirement... to be able to include charts in a document, but maybe that's just me?

I will really appreciate any advice or pointing me in the direction of good documentation.

The eventual solution was to rebuild the chart.  Here is an example:

```
function insertBarChart(body) {   
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("Score!B2:D7").getValues();
  var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable()
        .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, values[0][0])      
        .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, values[0][1])      
        .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, values[0][2])      
        .addRow(['Ownership', values[1][1], values[1][2]])   
        .addRow(['Control', values[2][1], values[2][2]])    
        .addRow(['Skills', values[3][1], values[3][2]])       
        .addRow(['Development', values[4][1], values[4][2]])   
        .addRow(['Social', values[5][1], values[5][2]])  
        .build(); 
  var chart = Charts.newColumnChart()      
    .setDataTable(dataTable)      
    .setColors(["green", "red"])      
    .setDimensions(600, 400)      
    .setXAxisTitle("Elements")      
    .setYAxisTitle("Points")      
    .setTitle("Profile")      
    .build();
  var scale = 0.5;
  var img = body.appendImage(chart.getAs('image/png'));
  img.setHeight(img.getHeight()*scale).setWidth(img.getWidth()*scale);
}
```

Comment: I did it using Chart API (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/), but you'll need rebuild your chart.

Comment: Thanks... I've tried that.  Rebuilding the chart as you suggested does work.

Answer (score 0):

(May 2017) Google seems to have fixed this. Your original code works for me and does not yield blank containers:

```
function insertChartImage(){
  var charts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Score Card').getCharts();
  var chart = charts[0].getAs('image/png');  // similar result with 'gif'
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);
  doc.getBody().appendImage(chart);          // similar result with insertImage()
}
```